# Internationalization of Codeigniter PHP application using an excel spreadsheet

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv, internationalization

I have a web app built on top of codeigniter. It's primarily in English but now I want to add support for other languages as well.

I'm familiar with Codeigniter's language library:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html

Which seems like a pretty good solution, however I have one problem. For each language, you must create a separate file of $lang[KEY] = VALUE statements. This means that if I want to have my Spanish speaking friend help me translate my application, they have to have the other file open next to the one they're working on. It can be pretty easy to lose track of your position.

I would like to translate this using a spreadsheet (csv) approach, picture something like this:
[image]

What are some ways I might go about accomplishing this? I've considered creating a 'master' spreadsheet for the application, and then writing a command-line php program to parse the csv file and create the appropriate language files which I would insert into my application. Is there a better way?

Comment: ...what about using the database, uh?

Comment: I'm not opposed to it, but wouldn't using the database be slightly more expensive than reading from a local file on the app server? (round trip time of database request)

Comment: With a db, you can load all the translations for a language at once, or use cache, or you can load only the required parts for a single page (using a column identifier, maybe)...With a CSV-like file you need to open/read/parse/process to extract the data each time you need a single string. DB can be optimized and it's meant to work like that. If you remain with your doubts you can always try both approaches and benchmark

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Making the authoring and maintenance of translations easier or parsing the CSV and generating the static files? I'm not sure what kind of answer you're after.

Comment: @Madmartigan, I think I've found the easiest way to manage translating and maintenance using my excel spreadsheet approach. I'm currently planning on using this spreadsheet as a master and writing a command line php program to generate the necessary _lang.php files for codeigniter's language library. I'm wondering if there is perhaps a better way.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your approach, but then again I have no idea what your workflow is. How often are you going to need to generate the files? How many translators are there? Does everyone need updated versions of all available languages? Is having to reference a master language file (the method you are avoiding) really that much of a burden?

Comment: There are about 10 translators and hopefully there wont be too many changes to the application that will require me to retranslate sections of it

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at this? http://codeigniter.com/wiki/LangBuilder